# Voltage rating for DIY power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc, switch-mode-power-supply

This is the first time I am building a DIY variable DC power supply using a SMPS and LTC3780 DC-DC Buck/Boost converter (5-32V input to 1V-30V 10A output). For most of my hobby projects 5-10A and 25-30V DC is sufficient. For the same power rating of 240W there are 24V and 48V supplies. I assume with 48V one I will have a bigger range of I & V combinations so it seems a better choice. However, I wonder about the voltage conversion efficiency. For 48V one, I will set it for 30V to be able to use it with the LTC3780 and then the buck converter will reduce it further as needed. So it will be 2x conversion essentially. Wouldn't it lose it's efficiency more than is needed?

On the other hand with the 24V supply there will voltage conversion once only and that will be by the step down converter. Besides if I need voltage higher than 24V the LTC3780 boost converter should accommodate it.

The price difference between the 24 & 48V supply is negligible. So which one would be a better choice? What do you suggest?

Comment: It’s easy to have things go wrong with stability of SMPS especially cascading for motor drives. So buy the best one instead.

Comment: Zaffresky, I pretty much always encourage DIY projects. Even fairly ambitious first-time stuff. But at this power level and *if this is your first power supply attempt* then I would recommend against attempting the idea and suggest you start with something less ambitious.  Can you tell us about your earlier power supply designs? As to choosing between 24 and 48 volts, were it me I'd go for higher voltage and less current. I don't usually need high currents. But I do often need higher DC voltages.

Comment: Regarding earlier designs, this is pretty much my first go at power supplies. For a less ambitious project do you suggest going for lower power rating/voltage or something else?

Comment: @jonk I am still curious about the point about efficiency as mentioned in my original post. Could you also please comment on that? :)

Comment: @Zaffresky I can't comment on what you wrote about *efficiency*. I'd have to spend time to go read what you've read. And I'm not prepared to do that. As to what more fitting but less ambitious project might look like, again I'd need to know more about your background and interests. For all I know you may be anything from a fledgling experimental physicist to a bright ten year old. But higher power involves a lot of issues (experience in dealing with dissipation being only one of many) that are at least somewhat ignorable if you select something an order of magnitude less.